# How do I make PM not getting involved into too complex technical tasks and trust developers instead?

Tags: project-management

**Background**

We are following agile and have daily & every 2 weeks scrum meetings. I am one of the guy who makes everything sound so easy including complex technical tasks which in turn makes my PM getting involved into complex technical discussions in order to help me in some cases or underestimate the more complex technical difficulties for given tasks, EVEN when he is not a technical person.

**Disadvantages of PM getting involved into complex technical talks**

- Now I not only need to find a fix to the complex solution but need to keep explaining to PM as well and as it gets more & more complicated it becomes harder and harder to explain.
- He thinks he knows the solution when he actually don't know, and I find it difficult to find right words to explain that it's not as easy as he thinks.
- I feel constant push to explain myself when not even necessary.

This has been happening with me for different projects/tasks and with different PMs. I ***realized the rest of the developers manage to talk in a way that they leave the PM satisfied and not ask any technical questions which in turn becomes their advantage e.g. PM believes everything they say***. I think I lack the story making skills (again not sure if the words are right).

Also none of the PMs had technical skills to help me with my projects.

**Question**

I am not sure what is the cause of above described behaviour but I think it's because I am explaining too much which makes PM getting involved into techincal discussion to help me when I don't need it.

- How do I make PM not getting involved into too complex technical tasks and trust me instead ?

Comment: Why do you see it as a problem if the PM gets involved in technical discussions? I don't understand why you are looking for non-existent problems, instead of focusing on your work.

Comment: Ok, so why is that a problem? If you don't need his help, then just listen to what he says, and do things your own way.

Comment: I asked you for clarification because it is not clear from your question. I don't really understand why you are looking for ways to prevent your PM from understanding your work. Anyway, you are free to emulate your colleagues and "confuse" your PM, not sure what you would gain by that though.

Comment: @MaskedMan Thank you for your help, most likely I have not chosen right words to explain what I want, your view of my question isn't right, let me reword it

Comment: @Change I agree with Masked Man, you are with the context you are providing us creating your own Problems. To me it sounds you pm is doing his job. You however just need to give an better summary of technical difficultys and Tasks. Confusing your PM wont even do you any good in he long run.

Comment: @MaskedMan please read my updated question, hopefully its more clear now

Comment: Can you explain why you have a PM when you are doing Scrum? There is no PM in Scrum.

Comment: nvoigt - read PM as scrummaster.

Comment: If you're a PM it's is much better to be able to explain to stakeholders that "Task X is taking 5 days because a new interface needs to be developed and tested to communicate with the database" than "we're late because the developer said it's difficult".

Comment: The problem is not your choice of words, the problem is your attitude. Rather than helping your PM gain a better understanding of the project, you are looking for ways to hide your knowledge and trick your PM into thinking that your work is way more complex than it actually is.

Answer (score 3):

**It's a good thing the PM gains technical knowledge.** That way he/she will understand the tasks better - which is good because the PM has to manage the project.

In my job I noticed it can help the PM tremendously when you explain what you need to do, and why other solutions aren't possible (summarized). **It makes it way easier for the PM to give a solid explanation to the client or to sell more time for the project.**

When the PM underestimates the complexity, just explain it a bit more and give your own time indication. Assessing delivery time should be done by people who execute the work (you - and your tech colleagues) so the PM can communicate this to the client. That's also why the PM shouldn't take over your job.

**Make clear what you're doing, why you need X time, and do your job. Correct the estimated time of delivery if needed. Thank your PM for the technical input, but do it your way.**